# Wrapping template of element directive in collection directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've two element directives `collection` and `element`, supposed to be used like this:

```html
<collection>
    <element/>
    <element/>
</collection>
```

They have templates:

**collection.html**

```html
<header>header</header>
<div><ul>...</ul></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

**element.html**

```html
<p>element</p>
```

What should be instead of `...` in `collection.html` to wrap each `element` with `<li>..</li>`?

**exprected result**

```
<header>header</header>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><p>element</p></li>
    <li><p>element</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

### update

On review of the task behind the question it appears that `element` tag actually is wrapper of nested HTML, and that simplifies things. So I have added an answer which describes how to use 2-level nested transclusion.

Comment: Why don't you wrap element in <li>'s inside of its template? Will it sometimes be used outside of lists?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put the `<li>` in the `element.html` like so `<li><p>element</p></li>`

Comment: @MarcKline It's a simplified code for better readability. In real code element wrapping html is too much bound to the collection template, and I dont want to copy-paste it on every kind of element (there are several types of them).

Comment: @Riron this workaround will not solve the issue, see my answer to MarcKline.

Comment: Then you might be able to wrap all children in a `<li>` using the jQlite `element.children()` in your `collection` directive. Looping through every child, and wraping it with a `<li>` might do it. See https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng/function/angular.element for more details on jQlite

Comment: I'm finishing up a Plunker to demo that as we speak :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-transclude` allows you to nest content inside of templated directives in such a way where you are able to manipulate the transcluded elements in the directive compile stage.

In this case, you need to use `transclude: 'element'` in order to transclude the *entire* `collection` element. This is because you need to operate on the children elements in a structured way (using `transclude: true` provides a flat array of *all* children nodes which doesn't work here).

```
.directive('collection', function(){
      return {
        transclude: 'element',
```

When using transclusion, a `transclude` function becomes available in the compile function of your directive. This function passes a single parameter, `clone`, which provides you with a clone of the transcluded content. When using `transclude: 'element`, the *entire* directive element is removed from the page. This requires you to add it back later.

```
compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
  return {
    pre: function(scope, element) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone){
```

To begin manipulating the content we'll add back, iterate over the cloned children elements, wrapping them with list item tags using the jqLite `wrap` function:

```
angular.forEach(clone.children(), function(el){
  var el = angular.element(el);
  el.replaceWith(el.wrap('<li></li>'));
});
```

Then create and store a new jqLite element from the HTML stored in the element passed into compile/link:

```
var html = angular.element(element.html());
```

Use jqLite `find` to select the `ul` element inside of it, and `append` the modified transclusion clone:

```
html.find('ul').append(clone);
```

... and finally replace the compile `element` with the finished product:

```
element.replaceWith(html);
```

You'll find a working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zKJKl2sOFfziw0lAfZ9f?p=preview).

Comment: This is good starting point, but question implies keeping wrapping html ('<li></li>') in the collection template, away from javascript. I'm going to modifiy your example a bit to look how to achieve it.

Comment: You can't keep it in the template. Transclusion without any JS manipulation such as this will only allow you to nest a single block (ie. you won't be able to wrap multiple elements such as what you show in your example).

Comment: Updated my answer with improvements that returns the entire template to the DOM (including non-transcluded content)

Comment: I've checked your example, and it's valid solution. However I dislike heavy jQuery manipulations and decided to rework whole concept. Now I'm using 2-layer nested transclusion and each 'item' define it's content in its inner html. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was not understanding task completely when I was asking this question.

But when I saw @MarcKline answer, I've got suspicious about validity of my question, because of the rule "*if you can't do it without jQuery in angular, you are probably doing something wrong*".

So I've changed concept on the `element` tags -  now they are containers too, and they have nested html, and work as wrappers too. So my final solution is:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){})
.directive('collection', function($compile){
  return {
    transclude: 'true',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<header>header</header><div><ul ng-transclude></ul></div><footer>footer</footer>',
  }
})
.directive('element', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template:  '<li><div ng-transclude></div></li>'
  }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <collection>
      <element>inner1</element>
      <element>inner2</element>
      <element>inner3</element>
    </collection>
</body>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxd1eb16qvD7ODADJVKo?p=preview)

Comment: This is why I made my initial comment on your question and what I would have suggested if you'd responded differently :)